# Only one checkbox selectble from each options group

Tags: jquery

Sorry for duplicate question. I found there are many questions about this topic but these are not helpful to me. I have several group of checkbox.

```
<div class="options">
   <input class="option" type="checkbox">
   <input class="option" type="checkbox">
   <input class="option" type="checkbox">
</div>

<div class="options">
   <input class="option" type="checkbox">
   <input class="option" type="checkbox">
   <input class="option" type="checkbox">
</div>

<div class="options">
   <input class="option" type="checkbox">
   <input class="option" type="checkbox">
   <input class="option" type="checkbox">
</div>
...
...
```

I want to only one checkbox can be selectable from each group. I have tried with jQuery but it work for every checkbox not for indivitual group of checkbox.

```
  $('body').on('change','.option', function() {
        $('.option').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
```

Another try with this

```
 $('body').on('change','.option', function() {
    $(this).parent('.options').find('.option').prop('checked', false);
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
  });
```

But no one solve my purpose. Please help.

Comment: Why don't you use radio buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method to get all the sibling elements or you can use radio button with the same name.

```js
 $('body').on('change', '.option', function() {
   $(this).siblings().prop('checked', false);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="options">
  <input class="option" type="checkbox">
  <input class="option" type="checkbox">
  <input class="option" type="checkbox">
</div>

<div class="options">
  <input class="option" type="checkbox">
  <input class="option" type="checkbox">
  <input class="option" type="checkbox">
</div>

<div class="options">
  <input class="option" type="checkbox">
  <input class="option" type="checkbox">
  <input class="option" type="checkbox">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

a better approach would be to use radio buttons, and give them all the same name.

```
<div class="options">
   <input name="myname" class="option" type="radio">
   <input name="myname" class="option" type="radio">
   <input name="myname" class="option" type="radio">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(":checkbox").change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
        $(this).siblings(":checkbox").prop("checked", false);
    }
});
```